# Cpanel subdomain only works in specific format

Tags: cpanel

I have recently created a subdomain in my cpanel. test.website.com was the intended address. However, when I type in website.com/test, the index page loads. If I type test.website.com, I get a server DNS address could not be found. Could it be because it hasn't propagated yet?

Hope I can get some help with this.

Comment: Yes, it may take up to 48 hours for the DNS changes to propagate throughout the Internet.

Please note that if the authoritative DNS servers of your domain name are different than the ones configured in WHM, you will have to create the 'test.website.com' subdomain in the DNS zone file.

Answer (score 0):

In DNS section of WHM ,under Edit DNS zone .. edit the primary DNS zone of the primary domain and make sure you have A record added for your sub domain.